# Will there be any problem if a passport is renewed before landing as a Permanent Resident in Canada?

Tags: canada

My existing passport has validity of one year plus and my Permanent Resident visa is stamped in this passport. However, recently I have early renewed my passport in order to avoid passport renewal within Canada as the embassy of my country will be in different city/ province from my destination city where I will be living.

In this situation will there be any problem if I land in Canada to confirm my Permanent Resident with new & old passport together?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any official source to back my information but I looked this up in various immigration forums and according to them, many people traveled like this in the past with the same situation as yours. (COPR immigrant visa on old passport and new valid passport). Just travel with both passports and be ready to explain your situation if needed. You can fill out a Web form to CIC and get this answer from themselves. Link [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/contacts/web-form.asp)

Some references that I looked up:

1. [Passport will expire during pr application process](https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/passport-will-expire-during-pr-application-process.529514/)
2. [Urgent Questions: Passport Renewal after getting CoPR](https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/urgent-questions-passport-renewal-after-getting-copr.499937/)

Answer (score 1):

[IRCC](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship.html)'s own internal document "[ENF 4 Port of entry examinations](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/resources/manuals/enf/enf04-eng.pdf)" specifically stated under section 13.18:

> Occasionally, documents containing valid visas are cancelled or replaced. If a valid visa inside an expired document is presented at the POE along with a valid passport or travel document, the visa is considered valid.

There are also some discussion and sharing about similar issue in another forums, for example, [these answers to the question "Landing with Renewed Passport. PR Visa on Old passport"](https://www.canadavisa.com/canada-immigration-discussion-board/threads/landing-with-renewed-passport-pr-visa-on-old-passport.570200/#post-7074927)